# substring function return column type instead of a value. Is there a way to fetch a value out of column type in pyspark

Tags: pyspark

I am comparing a condition with pyspark join in my application by using substring function. This function is returning a column type instead of a value.

```
substring(trim(coalesce(df.col1)), 13, 3) returns

Column<b'substring(trim(coalesce(col1), 13, 3)'>
```

Tried with expr but still getting the same column type result

```
expr("substring(trim(coalesce(df.col1)),length(trim(coalesce(df.col1))) - 2, 3)")
```

I want to compare the values coming from substring to the value of another dataframe column. Both are of string type

**pyspark:**

```
substring(trim(coalesce(df.col1)), length(trim(coalesce(df.col1))) -2, 3) == df2["col2"]
```

lets say `col1 = 'abcdefghijklmno'`

The expected output of substring function should `mno` based on the above definition.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

creating a sample dataframes to join

```
    list1 = [('ABC','abcdefghijklmno'),('XYZ','abcdefghijklmno'),('DEF','abcdefghijklabc')]
    df1=spark.createDataFrame(list1, ['col1', 'col2'])


    list2 = [(1,'mno'),(2,'mno'),(3,'abc')]
    df2=spark.createDataFrame(list2, ['col1', 'col2'])


import pyspark.sql.functions as f
```

creating a substring to read last n characters for three positions.

```
cond=f.substring(df1['col2'], -3, 3)==df2['col2']
newdf=df1.join(df2,cond)

>>> newdf.show()
+----+---------------+----+----+
|col1|           col2|col1|col2|
+----+---------------+----+----+
| ABC|abcdefghijklmno|   1| mno|
| ABC|abcdefghijklmno|   2| mno|
| XYZ|abcdefghijklmno|   1| mno|
| XYZ|abcdefghijklmno|   2| mno|
| DEF|abcdefghijklabc|   3| abc|
+----+---------------+----+----+
```

Comment: Thanks for the response. It is working with negative index. I was looking for a way if we can work it out with the length function too. will settle with negative index workaround for now.